# In Excel 365, how to remove the green "sharing" check indicator from the bottom-right of a workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, sharing

At some point, Excel added a green checkbox inside a very small window that floats in the bottom right of the workbook. It only shows when Excel is active and can be dragged to new locations (as was done below).

[image: Image of green sharing checkbox]

If you click on it, it will show a popup that says the workbook is "Not shared" and has a person icon (to share) and a 3-dot menu (with Copy Link, Open in Drive).

How do I get rid of it? It always shows up over the scroll bar and even if I move it, the next time I open it, it's back hovering over the scroll bar.

I tried to search for it, but get buried under responses on how to share, how to remove checkboxes (excel, not this thingie), etc.

This seems to be a new "feature" as I haven't seen it before. Or it may have been triggered by the work environment.

Comment: Can you move it so that it docks to a toolbar?

Comment: What build of Office 365 do you have installed? I was unable to reproduce with the current build 17126.20132 (2312)

Comment: @Ramhound - I have the same version as you.  If you don't have the check - it's either some setting I need to find OR only shows up if working in certain conditions (say on a shared drive).

Comment: are you using `Excel` in `IPad`? Have you tried to check the `Advanced Options` --> `Display Settings` or in `Review` Tab Ribbon under group `Protect`?

Comment: @Mayukh - This is Excel 365, latest version, running on Windows 11.  Yes, I have gone through all the settings (including advanced) and found nothing that appears to relate to the sharing checkbox.

Comment: On further testing - it only shows when the Excel sheet is saved to a cloud folder (Google in this case.)  The box can be docked on the left or right, but not top or bottom.  It's not clear if this is an Excel issue when files are stored in the cloud or something that Google drive is causing.

Comment: hmm I see, even I am using `Windows 11` but I am not able to find tried all option to get that, but are you still facing this issue? Can you show a `.gif` if possible?

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya - The green checkbox is in the image posted in the actual post. What do you want the .gif file to show? I will try to get some time to test to see if it is just Google Drive or also OneDrive related.

Comment: According to this post in the Microsoft forum, this behavior is caused by the Google Drive desktop app.  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-disable-this-file-not-shared-with-anyone/b1d1fbb3-f162-4ffe-aad1-f831d5b08c57?page=2

Comment: Here's another Microsoft forum post about it: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-can-i-remove-the-green-checkbox-floating/b9e3d00b-11dc-4d35-b262-975eb3b47fc7

Comment: Here's a Google Support post about it: https://support.google.com/drive/thread/46241453/remove-green-check-in-microsoft-excel-document-from-google-drive?hl=en

Comment: @PauldeBarros - your comment about the incorrect post was correct, so I deleted the answer - thanks.  Your links are good, but none of them actually explains how to remove the checkbox that Google Drive is overlaying there..